# Specify types of parameters for function from other function definition

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a wrapper function to load API's from Google's GAPI library.

The type definitions for the libraries I am trying to load are specified in their own `@types/gapi.client.<api>` definition file, and the function I am trying to wrap is implemented in a standardized format in each of the library's definition file. For example:

To load the Calendar API, this type definition is specified in the `@types/gapi.client.calendar` .d.ts file:

```
namespace gapi.client {
...
function load(name: 'calendar', version: 'v3', callback: () => any): void;
...
}
...
```

Similarly, this is the definition of the load function from the Drive API's .d.ts  file:

```
namespace gapi.client {
...
function load(name: 'drive', version: 'v3', callback: () => any): void;
...
}
...
```

Is there any way to narrow the types of my own wrapper function to include the parameters specified by each of the libraries' definition file? This doesn't work, but is my best guess at trying to show what I am trying to accomplish:

```
private loadApi<T>(
  api: Parameters<typeof gapi.client.load>[0], 
  version: Parameters<typeof gapi.client.load>[1],
  observer: ReplaySubject<T>
) {
...
}
```

This seems to only pick the Drive library definitions for the client namespace, rather than inferring that 'calendar' or 'drive' could be used as input parameters. Ideally, I would like the function to know what types are allowed based on the generic, however I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: This is actually not easy at all due to some language limitations (specifically, union of overloaded signatures actually creates intersection, not union -- because of some TS internals). But in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32164) GitHub issue several very clever guys came up with some solutions, which seem to work.